# Strange error with Twitter rate limiting and Azure

Tags: .net, twitter, azure

I have an Azure worker role. It requests the information of 100 users. I load the data with XDocument.Load. I save the requestet data in a blob on azure. Everything works fine locally.

When I upload the app to Azure it fails, and yes, I know of rate limiting with Twitter, but it doesn't matter if I wait...let's say... 2 hours to request the same data again, I still get the The "remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request", which indicates rate limiting with Twitter.

I am really lost, especially because of the waitng-game with twitter and rate limiting on Azure, it's not an easy task to debug either.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that Azure does not give you a dedicated IP so other apps are probably sharing the IP and using up the rate limit. You will have to make the requests authenticated or use an IP limited only to your app.

Comment: I created a new service, added authentication with the Twitterize API and now it workes. Thank you!

Comment: Incorrect.  While there is no guarantee that your IP address will not change over time, your Web/Worker Role maintains a unique IP address that is *NOT* shared with other apps.